# Problem related to remainder

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, number-systems

A polynomial in $x$ leaves a remainder $2$ and $3$ when divided by $x-1$ and $x+1$. What is the remainder, when divided by $x^2-1$ ?

Comment: hint: $(x-1)(x+1) = x^2-1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**.  The remainder will be a linear polynomial, say $ax+b$, and you need to determine $a$ and $b$.  The division can be written as
$$f(x)=(x^2-1)q(x)+ax+b\ .$$
From the given information you have
$$f(x)=(x-1)r(x)+2\ .$$
Now substituting $x=1$ in these two equations will give some information about $a$ and $b$, and you can use the other given remainder in a similar way to get a second equation.  You can then solve for $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Though it can be done by (Lagrange) interpolation, it is just as simple (and more powerful) to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT), which is $\color{#c00}{\rm very\ easy}$ when the $\color{#c00}{\rm Bezout}$ identity is known

By CRT, $ $ if $\ \color{#c00}{j g} + \color{#c00}{k h} = 1\,$ then $\ \begin{eqnarray}f\equiv a\!\!\!\pmod g\\f\equiv b\!\!\!\pmod h\end{eqnarray}$ $\!\iff\!\!$ $\begin{eqnarray} f&\equiv&\  a\,\color{#c00}{kh}\, +\, b\,\color{#c00}{jg}&&({\rm mod}\ {gh})\\  &\equiv& a+(b\!-\!a)\color{#c00}{jg}&&({\rm mod}\ gh)\end{eqnarray}$

Hence $\ \frac{1}{2} \underbrace{(x\!+\!1)}_{\large g}-\frac{1}2\underbrace{(x\!-\!1)}_{\large h} = 1\,$ and $\,\ a,b = 3,2\ \Rightarrow\ f\equiv 3-\color{#c00}{\frac{1}2(x\!+\!1)} \pmod{\!\!x^2\!-\!1}$

**Remark** $\ $ It was $\,\color{#c00}{\rm easy}$ here since $\,\ g\ {\rm mod}\ h = g - h = (x\!+\!1)-(x\!-\!1) = 2\ $ is invertible in $\,\Bbb Q\,$ hence scaling by $\,1/2\,$ yields the Bezout identity, which immediately yields the solution as above. Generally it is just as easy when $\ g\ {\rm mod}\ h\ $ is invertible (which is equivalent to the extended Euclidean algorithm (EEA) terminating in $1$ step, i.e. this is an *optimization* of the EEA). In particular, the EEA terminates in one step if one of the polynomials is *linear*.

Since Lagrange interpolation is the special case of CRT when both moduli are *linear* polynomials, the above optimization always applies.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3177321/242) for a convenient general approach using this method of transforming the Bezout GCD identity.

Answer (score -1):

Let $\displaystyle f(x)=(x^2-1)g(x)+A(x-1)+B(x+1)$ where $g(x)$ is a polynomial and $A,B$ are constants

Using Polynomial [remainder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem) theorem, $\displaystyle2=f(1)=B\cdot(1+1)\iff B=1$

Similarly,  $\displaystyle3=f(-1)=A(-1-1)\iff A=?$

Comment: You should justify why there exists such a representation of $f\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque, Because the remainder by a Quadratic Polynomial will be a linear Polynomial $$A(x-1)+B(x+1)=x(A+B)+B-A=x a+b$$

Comment: You need more, i.e. generally it is not true that if $\,f_1,f_2\,$ are polynomials of degree $\,1\,$ then every polynomial of degree $\le 1$ has form $\, A f_1 + B f_2,\,$ e.g. it is false if $\,f_1 = C f_2.\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque, Here $a,b$ are constants may be zero, too. I  should written : "will be at  most a linear Polynomial"

Comment: Yes, I know $A,B$ are constants. That doesn't fix it, see the mentioned counterexample.