# Remainder of polynomial product, CRT solution via Bezout

Tags: polynomials

Given:
$$f(x) \pmod{x^2 + 4} = 2x + 1$$
$$f(x) \pmod{x^2 + 6} = 6x - 1$$

Define r(x) as:
$$f(x) \pmod{(x^2 + 4)(x^2+6)} = r(x)$$

What is $r(4)$?

---

The 3 equations can be restated as quotient · divisor + remainder:

$$f(x) = a(x)(x^2 + 4) + 2x + 1 $$
$$f(x) = b(x)(x^2 + 6) + 6x - 1 $$
$$f(x) = c(x)(x^2 + 4)(x^2 + 6) + r(x) = c(x)(x^4 + 10x^2 + 24) + r(x) $$

---

Note this isn't homework, and there are several different methods that can be used to solve this, one of which produces an f(x) based on the 2 given remainders, two of which produce r(x) without having to determine f(x), and a slight variation that produces r(4). I've looked at other polynomial remainder questions here at SE, but those did not involve all of the methods that I'm aware of that can be used to solve this particular problem, so I thought it might be interesting for others here at SE. Some, but not all of the methods are related to Chinese remainder theorem, so I wasn't sure if should also tag this question with Chinese remainder theorem. I found this problem at another forum site, so I'm not sure of the origins of this particular problem.

Comment: Please give some context, in particular, tell us what you've tried so far, including anything you had difficulty with. Also, letting us know where this problem comes from would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnOmielan - this problem is already solved, but depending on the method used to solve it, there are some difficulties that can be overcome by altering the approach, which I thought might be interesting to others here at SE.

Comment: Thanks for your response & question text update. Please initially include any such context in your future questions.

Comment: @JohnOmielan  - brain fade on my part, I was in the process of composing the context when I got called away and forgot to go back and copy / paste the context into my question. I'll pay more attention next time.

Comment: Please give details on the other methods you mention.

Comment: @BillDubuque - to produce an f(x), 2 long divisions were done in reverse, starting with the 2 given divisors and remainders working backwards, with the goal of producing a common f(x). This is somewhat of a trial and error process, but I only had to do one retry for the x^2 term. f(x) ended up at a 6th degree polynomial.

Comment: @BillDubuque - I updated my question for the other methods. If f(x) is evaluated at the 2 roots of (x^2+4), the 1st and 3rd equation become f(x) = (a(x) · 0) + 2x + 1 and f(x) = (c(x) · 0) + r(x) = r(x). If f(x) is evaluated at the 2 roots of (x^2 + 6), the 2nd and 3rd equations become f(x) = (b(x) · 0) + 6x - 1 and f(x) = (c(x) · 0) + r(x) = r(x). Evaluating f(x) at the 4 roots (f(x) = 2x+1 or 6x-1 for the 4 roots) results in 4 pairs of x and f(x) == r(x), enough to use Lagrange interpolation for r(x) <= degree 3, but all of the values are complex numbers, making interpolation difficult.

Comment: @BillDubuque - there hasn't been much response to this question, but I'll wait for a few more days. Considering there are several methods, would it be ok include 2 or 3 of them and then a link to a thread at another forum which would include more of the methods (rather than posting a lengthy answer with 4 or 5 methods)?

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful to add those to your answer. It's not clear from what you wrote how the "long division in reverse" works.

Comment: @BillDubuque - I posted answer showing the long division. Even though this gives away the answer, my impression is that the intended answers should show the steps using one of several methods that can produce r(x) or calculate r(4) without having to determine f(x), The focus of this question should be about discovering and explaining the methods to used solve it, rather than just come up with the result of r(4). If you feel this is inappropriate, I can delete the answer and wait for responses.

Comment: I posted what I suspect is the intended solution (read off the CRT solution from the obvious Bezout equation).

Comment: @BillDubuque - I updated my answer to show two more methods. The last method in my answer takes advantage of the fact that (x^2+6)-((x^2+4) = 2, but in a different manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ We can [read off a CRT solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2060729/242) from the Bezout equation for the gcd of the moduli, viz. $$\bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{\text{$\color{#90f}{\text{scale}}$ the Bezout equation by the residue difference - then ${\rm \color{#c00}{re}\color{#0a0}{arrange}}$}}$$
$$\begin{align}
{\rm if}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ &\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\begin{array}{rr} &f\equiv\,  f_g\pmod{\!g}\\ &f\equiv\, f_h\pmod{\! h} \end{array}\ \ {\rm and}\ \ \gcd(g,h) = 1\\[.4em]
{\rm then}\ \ \  f_g - f_h\, &=:\ \delta\qquad\qquad\ \ \rm residue\ difference \\[.2em] 
\times\qquad\quad\ \ \ 1\ &=\ \ a g\, +\, b h\quad\ \rm Bezout\ equation\ for \ \gcd(g,h) \\[.5em]\hline
\Longrightarrow\ \,f_g\, \color{#c00}{-\, f_h}\, &= \color{#0a0}{\delta ag} + \delta bh\quad\ \rm product\ of \ above\ (= {\color{#90f}{scaled}}\ Bezout)\\[.2em]
\Longrightarrow \underbrace{f_g \color{#0a0}{- \delta ag}}_{\!\!\!\large \equiv\ f_{\large g}\! \pmod{\!g}}\! &= \underbrace{\color{#c00}{f_h} + \delta bh}_{\large\!\! \equiv\ f_{\large h}\! \pmod{\!h}}\ \ \ \underset{\large {\rm has\ sought\ residues}\phantom{1^{1^{1^{1^1}}}}\!\!\!}{\rm \color{#c00}{re}\color{#0a0}{arranged}\ product}\rm\! = {\small CRT}\ solution\end{align}  $$

More generally: $ $  if the gcd $\,d\neq 1\,$ then [it is solvable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2060729/242) $\iff d\mid f_g-f_h\,$ and we can use the same method we used below for $\,d=\color{#c00}2\!:\,$ scale the Bezout equation by $\,(f_g-f_h)/d = \delta/d.\,$ Since  $\,\color{#c00}2\,$ is invertible in the OP, we could have scaled the Bezout equation by $\,1/2\,$ to change $\,\color{#c00}2\,$ to $\,1,\,$ but not doing so avoids (unneeded) fractions so  simplifies the arithmetic.

In our specific problem we have the major simplification that  the Bezout equation is obvious being simply the moduli *difference* $ =\color{#c00}2$
hence $\ \ \smash[t]{\overbrace{\color{0a0}{6x\!-\!1}-\color{#90f}{(2x\!+\!1)}}^{\rm residue\ difference}} = \overbrace{(2x\!-\!1)}^{\!\text{scale LHS}}\,\overbrace{\color{#c00}2 = (\color{0a0}{x^2\!+\!6}-\color{#0a0}{(x^2\!+\!4)}}^{{\overbrace{\textstyle\color{#c00}2\, =\, x^2\!+\!6-(x^2\!+\!4)_{\phantom{|_{|_i}}}\!\!\!\!}^{\Large \text{Bezout equation}}}})\overbrace{(\color{#0a0}{2x\!-\!1})}^{\text{scale RHS}},\ $ which rearranged

yields $\ \ \underbrace{\color{}{6x\!-\!1 - (\color{#0a0}{2x\!-\!1})(x^2\!+\!6)}}_{\large 
 \equiv\ \ 6x\ -\ 1\ \pmod{x^2\ +\ 6}\!\!\!}\, =\,  \underbrace{\color{#90f}{2x\!+\!1} -\color{#0a0}{(2x\!-\!1)(x^2\!+\!4)}}_{\large \equiv\ \ 2x\ +\ 1\ \pmod{x^2\ +\ 4}\!\!\!} =\,r(x) =\, $  CRT solution.

---

**Remark** $ $ If ideals and cosets are familiar then the above can be expressed more succinctly as

$$  \bbox[12px,border:2px solid #c00]{f_g\! +\! (g)\,\cap\, f_h\! +\! (h) \neq \phi \iff f_g-f_h \in (g)+(h)}\qquad$$

Comment: So simple it can all be all be done *purely mentally* in a minute once you grasp the **key idea** that scaling the Bezout equation by the residue difference - then rearranging - [yields the CRT solution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2060729/242)

Comment: Good answer. You might want to enclose 2x-1, 2x+2, 6x-1 and x^2+6 in parenthesis for consistency.

Comment: @rcgldr The paren's are used only when needed (standard algebraic syntax / operator precedence), I don't distribute the negative sign into $\,{-}(2x+1)\,$ etc because this makes the rearranging clearer - just negate the *single* sign factor when moving it to the opposite side of the equation. Also it preserves the form of the moduli and residues - making it clearer how the method works in  general.

Comment: Since the original question only asks about r(4), there should be a path or insight to conclude r(x) = (d(x))(x^2+4)+(2x+1) = (d(x))(x^2+6)+(6x-1).  Then 11 · (1st equation) - 10 · (2nd equation) = (d(x))(x^2-16) + 11(2x+1)  - 10(6x-1), and for x = 4, r(4) = (d(4)·0) + 11(2·4+1) - 10(6·4-1) = -131, without having to determine d(x). I was planning on adding this as a fourth method on my answer.

Comment: @rcgldr Evaluating $\, r = f_g- \delta ag = 2x\!+\!1 - (2x\!-\!1)(x^2\!+\!4)\,$ at $\,x=4\,$ is already extremely simple. I doubt you'll find anything much simpler than that (assuming the Bezout equation is known).

Comment: True, but since the original question asks for r(4), it would seem the intended solution would solve for r(4) without having to solve for r(x) or f(x). This is what I was considering in my prior comment. Although you can solve for d(x) = (-2x+1) (as used in my prior comment), the question can be answered without solving for d(x).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Observe that $\gcd(x^2+4, x^2+6)=1$ and 
$$\frac{1}{2}(x^2+6)-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+4)=1.$$
Now apply Chinese remainder theorem to the system
\begin{align*}
f(x) & \equiv 2x+1 \pmod{x^2+4}\\ 
f(x) & \equiv 6x-1 \pmod{x^2+6} 
\end{align*}
To get something like:
$$f(x) \equiv \underbrace{(2x+1)(\ldots) + (6x-1)(\ldots)}_{r(x)} \pmod{(x^2+4)(x^2+6)}.$$

Comment: The question has been updated with context I initially forgot to include, that the problem is already solved using several methods. So assuming that r(x) = (2x+1)(a(x)) + (6x-1)(b(x)), how would you determine a(x) and b(x)?

Comment: There is a method that starts with 1/2(x^+6) - 1/2(x^2+4) = 1 to end up with r(x) = (2x+1)(...) + (6x-1)(...), but I'm wondering if the approach you are considering is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting an "answer" for alternative methods. The third method below is the most straight forward, exploiting the fact that $(x^2+6)-(x^2+4) = 2$. The answer to the question, r(4) = -131.

Using a "reverse" long division process to produce a common f(x) based on the first two given equations will work, but, although this solves the problem, I doubt that is the intended solution, since it involves a reasoned trial and error search for f(x) (sort of an optimized brute force search), and it is my impression that a proper answer should be able to solve for r(x) or specifically for r(4) without having to determine f(x).

Below is what the process looks like. f(x) (the dividend) and the quotients a(x), b(x) are unknown. The divisors and remainders are given in the first two equations of the question. You start at the bottom of these two long hand divisions in parallel, working upwards to produce a common f(x).

As mentioned, this is a reasoned trial an error process. For example, my first attempt at the x^2 term of f(x) was 13x^2, which failed later, the second attempt was 25x^2, which worked (at least it produces a common f(x) that satisfies the first two equations). For the rest of the terms, the first attempts at terms for a common f(x) (and the corresponding quotient terms of a(x) and b(x)) worked.

Consider the very first step, f(x) / (x^2+4) has remainder ...+1, f(x) / (x^2+6) has remainder ...-1. This suggests that the last term of f(x) is 5 and the last terms of both  quotients are 1, since 5-4 = +1 and 5-6 = -1. The x terms in the remainder show that after subtraction from the third step from the bottom, x terms are 2x for division by (x^2+4) and 6x for division by (x^2+6), and setting the x term of f(x) to 18 works as 18 - (4·4) = 2 and 18 - (2·6) = 6. The process is continued upwards, looking for common f(x) terms that satisfy both long hand divisions. This is the final result. Again note that this process is started at the bottom and worked upwards to produce a common f(x) (dividend) for both divisors:

```
              1  1  6  4  1                   1  1  4  2  1
      ---------------------           ---------------------
1 0 4 | 1  1 10  8 25 18  5     1 0 6 | 1  1 10  8 25 18  5
        1  0  4                         1  0  6
           1  6  8                         1  4  8
           1  0  4                         1  0  6       
              6  4 25                         4  2 25
              6  0 24                         4  0 24
                 4  1 18                         2  1 18                  
                 4  0 16                         2  0 12   
                    1  2  5                         1  6  5
                    1  0  4                         1  0  6
                       2  1                            6 -1
```

Once any f(x) is determined that satisfies the first two given equations, then the rest just requires normal division.

$$f(x) = x^6 + x^5 + 10 x^4 + 8 x^3 + 25 x^2 + 18 x + 5$$

Expressing f(x) as quotient ·  divisor + remainder for the different divisors:

$$f(x) = (x^4 +  x^3 +  6x^2 +  4x +  1)(x^2 + 4) + 2x + 1 $$
$$f(x)= (x^4 +  x^3 +  4x^2 +  2x +  1)(x^2 + 6) + 6x - 1 $$
$$f(x) = (x^2 + x)(x^4 + 10x^2 + 24) -2 x^3 + x^2 - 6 x + 5 $$

---

Using typical remainder theorem approach
f(x) evaluated at the 4 roots of (x^2+4)(x^2+6):
$$f(x) = c(x))(x^2+4)(x^2+6)) = r(x)$$
$$f(x) = (c(x) · 0) + r(x) = r(x)$$
f(x) evaluated at the 2 roots of (x^2+4):
$$f(x) = (a(x) · 0) + 2x + 1) = 2x + 1$$
f(x) evaluated at the 2 roots of (x^2+6):
$$f(x) = (b(x) · 0) + 6x - 1) = 6x - 1$$
This leads to 4 data points for r(x):
$${-(2)i,-(4)i+1}$$
$${+(2)i,+(4)i+1}$$
$${-\sqrt{6}i,-(6)\sqrt{6}i-1}$$
$${-\sqrt{6}i,-(6)\sqrt{6}i-1}$$

Using Lagrange interpolation to solve for r(x) is complicated due to the complex numbers:

```
r(x) = ((x-x1)(x-x2)(x-x3)(y0))/((x0-x1)(x0-x2)(x0-x3)) +
       ((x-x0)(x-x2)(x-x3)(y1))/((x1-x0)(x1-x2)(x1-x3)) +
       ((x-x0)(x-x1)(x-x3)(y2))/((x2-x0)(x2-x1)(x2-x3)) +
       ((x-x0)(x-x1)(x-x2)(y3))/((x3-x0)(x3-x1)(x3-x2)) +
```

grinding the 4 terms leads to:

```
r(x) = (1/2 + i/8) (x^3 - 2 i x^2 + 6 x - 12 i) +
       (1/2 - i/8) (x^3 + 2 i x^2 + 6 x + 12 i) +
       1/24 (( i sqrt(6) - 36) x + 36 i sqrt(6) + 6) (x^2 + 4) +
       1/24 ((-i sqrt(6) - 36) x - 36 i sqrt(6) + 6) (x^2 + 4)
r(x) =    x^3 + 1/2 x^2 +  6 x + 3 +
       -3 x^3 + 1/2 x^2 - 12 x + 2
r(x) = -2 x^3 +     x^2 -  6 x + 5
```

---

Exploiting the fact that $(x^2+6) - (x^2+4) = 2$ :

$$f(x) = a(x)(x^2+4)+(2x+1)$$
$$f(x) = b(x)(x^2+6)+(6x-1)$$
multiply 1st equation by $(x^2+6)$ and 2nd equation by $(x^2+4)$
$$f(x)(x^2+6) = a(x)(x^2+4)(x^2+6)+(2x+1)(x^2+6)$$
$$f(x)(x^2+4) = b(x)(x^2+4)(x^2+6)+(6x-1)(x^2+4)$$
subtracting 4th equation from 3rd:
$$2f(x) = a(x)(x^2+4)(x^2+6)+(2x+1)(x^2+6)-b(x)(x^2+4)(x^2+6)-(6x-1)(x^2+4)$$
$$f(x) = (1/2)(a(x)(x^2+4)(x^2+6)+(2x+1)(x^2+6)-b(x)(x^2+4)(x^2+6)-(6x-1)(x^2+4))$$
$$f(x) mod((x^2+4)(x^2+6)) = r(x) = (1/2)((2x+1)(x^2+6) - (6x-1)(x^2+4))$$
$$r(x) = -2x^3 + x^2 - 6x + 5$$

Comment: The last method essentially rederives one form of CRT, namely if $\,\gcd(g,h)=1\,$ then

$$\large \begin{align} &f\equiv f_g\!\!\pmod{g}\\ &f\equiv f_h\!\!\pmod{h}\end{align} \iff f \equiv \dfrac{ f_g\, h - f_h\,g}{\color{#c00}{\ h\,-\,g}}\!\!\pmod{\!gh}$$

This is particularly simple here because $\,\color{#c00}{h - g} =  x^2+6-(x^2+4) = \color{#c00}2\,$ is trivially invertible. $\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque - true, but I was unaware of CRT when I first did the last method. I was just looking for some way to remove a(x), b(x), and c(x) from the equations.